# kubernetes: NetworkPolicy deny-all not denying

Tags: kubernetes, weave, kubernetes-security

I am deploying an application on a `kubernetes` cluster on `aws` with `weave`

I have one additional (besides the `default`) namespace: `my-staging`.

I want to apply and test the following deny-all policy which is suggested by [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#default-deny-all-ingress-traffic):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: staging-default-deny-all
  namespace: my-staging
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

I then spin up a `busybox` for testing purposes in the default namespace:

```
kubectl run busybox --rm -ti --image=busybox /bin/sh  --namespace=default
```

...and my `ui` service (supposed to be listening on port `80`) in `my-staging` namespace is reachable!

```
/ # wget --spider ui.staging-els.svc.cluster.local
Connecting to ui.staging-els.svc.cluster.local (100.68.222.37:80)
```

Why is this happening?

p.s. I am applying the `NetworkPolicy` while the app has already been deployed if this is of any significance.

**update**: this must be a **weave** thing cause when deleting my cluster and re-creating with `--networking calico` everything worked out without any issue whatsoever.

Comment: I have answered your question at https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/issues/3219

Answer (score 0):

In order for your namespace to have a default-deny policy you need to annotate it:

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-staging
  annotations:
    net.beta.kubernetes.io/network-policy: |
      {
        "ingress": {
          "isolation": "DefaultDeny"
        }
      }
```

You will then only need policies for explicitly enabling connectivity between pods.

For more information, refer to docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/weave-network-policy/

Comment: so the `namespece` definition in this `yml` file removes the necessity of an explicit network policy as the one I cited? or are both things (your annotation and my default deny policy) needed? or is this a `waeve`-specific thing so just this annotation is needed to achieve default-deny?

Comment: in any case updating the ns with the above definition still makes the service discoverable from default namespace ...